# Are there any real-world fonts out there that specify an encoding in the top dict of the CFF table?

Tags: ruby, fonts, truetype, typography, opentype

I am currently working on implementing support for the CFF table and charstrings in the [TTFunk](https://github.com/prawnpdf/ttfunk) library. At the moment I'm trying to write tests for the CFF table's encoding structure, but I'm having a devil of a time finding a real-world font that actually specifies an encoding. CID fonts don't specify one, and all the non-CID fonts I've looked at use one of the predefined encodings ("standard" or "expert"). I've downloaded thousands of fonts and for the life of me can't find anything. Can anyone point me to a font that has one of these encoding structures, or is it more of an academic thing that nobody actually uses?

Comment: You probably want to ask this question over on http://typedrawers.com, in the font technology subforum. I suspect you're looking at CFF-when-embedded-in-PDF for that test case, but I can't say I ever checked. (Asking on the opentype mailing list might also yield an answer sooner than here on SO)

Comment: Great, thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I'll give those avenues a shot :)

Comment: Posted over on Typedrawers: http://typedrawers.com/discussion/2718/real-world-fonts-that-include-an-encoding-in-their-cff-table/p1?new=1

Comment: Also, because I know Adobe is already working on this, CFF recently got updated to the [CFF2 spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2) for use specifically in opentype fonts (rather than as datablock to be embedded in "something"), which'll be well worth implementing in parallel. It ditched the local encoding/charset and just relies on `cmap` and `post` =)